# Jquery selectbox make option - links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

js:

```
   $('#user').selectbox({
           onOpen: function (inst) {
               console.log("open", inst);
           },
           onClose: function (inst) {
               console.log("close", inst);
           },
           onChange: function (val, inst) {

           console.log(val);

           },
           effect: "fade"
       });
```

html:

```
  <select id="user">
                                        <option><?= $user_name ?></option>
                                        <option>
                                            <a href="/">profile</a>
                                        </option>
                                        <option>
                                            <a href="/">Exit</a>
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
```

I want to make the options of the jquery selectbox to be a link, not just text, but how to put a link inside an option using this plugin>

Answer (score 2):

if i may suggest another solution:

```
$('#user').change(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

and the option:

```
<option value="http://www.google.com" >profile</option>
```